# Update grid and form simultaneously

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, grid, extjs5

My app has a grid and a form (for record detail).

when I update a record I intended to be simultaneously updated the grid and the form (before store.sync()).

Any idea how to do this?

In the case of my fiddle, after the update (edit button), the form only updates if you click in another grid row and re-click again on the edited row.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12v7

EDITED: see comments.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data binding: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12vb)

```
Ext.define('ViewerModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.viewermodel',

    stores: {
        mystore: {

            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224'
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234'
            }, {
                name: 'Homer',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244'
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: ''
            }]
        }
    }
});


Ext.define('APP.HorizontalBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'layout-horizontal-box',
    width: 800,
    height: 300,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    viewModel: {
        type: 'viewermodel'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        flex: 1,
        margin: '0 10 0 0',
        bind: {
            store: '{mystore}',
            selection: '{user}'
        },

        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 2
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone',
            flex: 2
        }],

        tbar: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'name',
                bind: '{user.name}'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'email',
                bind: '{user.email}'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'phone',
                bind: '{user.phone}'
            }]
        }],
    }, {
        xtype: 'form',
        flex: 1,
        margin: '0 10 0 0',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name',
            bind: '{user.name}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            name: 'email',
            bind: '{user.email}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Phone',
            name: 'phone',
            bind: '{user.phone}'
        }]
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('APP.HorizontalBox', {
            renderTo: document.body,
            width: 800,
            height: 400
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. In my  fiddle example your solution works well. However, in another grid of my app I can not implement the same solution, because I use in the grid one templatecolumn and a template in the grid panel. Any idea how to solve this case?  I edited my post with another fiddle to illustrate this part.